# Path of ${1#*=}?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell

What does `pluginPath="${1#*=}` signify as per path in linux.

It is from openfoam's parafoam from directory by the way `\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\usr\lib\openfoam\openfoam2306\bin`

was trying to change it to some other path for paraview

Comment: @Marius_Couet not really. That covers substitution but what's shown here is pattern matching and replacement

Answer (score 5):

In a POSIX-style shell script, `${1#*=}` would mean "the first positional parameter string specified for this script or shell function, with everything from the beginning of the string to the left-most `=` character omitted".

So, if `parafoam` is a script that begins like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
pluginPath="${1#*=}"
```

Then if it is invoked like `parafoam foo=/some/path bar baz`,
then the `pluginPath` variable assignment will be equivalent to

```
pluginPath="/some/path"
```

In other words, such an assignment means that the value of `pluginPath` is expected to be specified by whatever calls that script or shell function.